# IE8 doesn't show extjs gridpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid panel that is not shown in IE8 but everything works fine in ff and opera. here's my code:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

    <style type="text/css">
    .x-grid3-cell-inner, .x-grid3-hd-inner  {white-space: inherit;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    var sData=[["7039","","","dummy value","Application Administrator","Application Administrator","89/9/14?? 14:37:02 (GMT+03:30)","dummy value"],["8198","","","dummy value s","Application Administrator","","","dummy value"],["8247","","","dummy value","Application Administrator","","","dummy value"],["8261","","","dummy value","Application Administrator","","","dummy value"]];

    Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        var store = new Ext.data.Store({
            data: sData,
            reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
                envelope_id: 'envelope_id'
            }, ['envelope_id', 'status_id', 'workflow_name', 'name','created_by_full_name','modified_by_full_name', {
                name: 'modified_datetime',                
            }, 'step_name'])
        });

        function linkFactory(val,x,store){
             return '<a href="/workflow/envelope/EnvelopeProperties.jsp?id='+store.data.envelope_id+'">'+val+'</a>';

        }
        function del(val){

            return '<a href="javascript:abortEnvelope(\''+val+'\', \'personal\')"><img src="../images/icons/toolbar-gen-cancel_on.gif" /></a>';}

        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            renderTo: Ext.get('mydiv'),
            frame: true,
            width: 520,
            stripeRows: true,
            enableColumnMove: false,
            store: store,
            columns: [
                      {header: "dummy value", width: 235,renderer:linkFactory, dataIndex: 'name',sortable:true,css: 'white-space:normal;'},
                    {header: "dummy value",width:85 ,dataIndex: 'step_name',sortable:true},
                    {header: "dummy value",width:120,dataIndex: 'modified_datetime',sortable:true,css: 'white-space:normal;'},                    
                    {header: "dummy value ", dataIndex: 'workflow_name',sortable:true,hidden:true,css: 'white-space:normal;'},
                    {header: "dummy value ", dataIndex: 'created_by_full_name',sortable:true,hidden:true,css: 'white-space:normal;'},
                    {header: "dummy value", dataIndex: 'modified_by_full_name',sortable:true,hidden:true,css: 'white-space:normal;'},
                    {renderer:del,width:25,dataIndex: 'envelope_id',hideable:false}
                      ]
        });

    });    
    </script>
</form>
```

We are using extjs 2.0. I have no idea which part is causing trouble. Any idea?!

Comment: I wanted to help you, but it works fine in my IE8 :(. I have ext-3.3.0 but I don't think this matters in this case. maybe you will try 'mydiv' instead of Ext.get('mydiv') in renderTo config property or try to indicate height config property. May be you will give more info... I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were using a modified and localized version of extjs. After using the original version, the problem solved. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have no height set. Use:

```
renderTo: 'mydiv',
height: 500
```

Does 'mydiv' exist in your page?

Comment: Thank you for your support. The problem occurred because we were using a modified version of extjs which was not compatible with IE.